# Condition in jle (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, conditional-statements, att

I am starting to learn Assembly.
In the first `jle` that I have, I know that means to jump to .L3 if something is lesser, but, I don't understand where it compares the two values, isn´t supposed that the `cmpl` appear before the `jle` or it´s the same thing?

```
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
        jle     .L3
        movl    %edx, %ecx
        sall    $4, %ecx
        cmpl    %ecx, %eax
        jge     .L3
        .p2align 2,,3
.L6:
        addl    %edx, %ebx
        imull   %edx, %eax
        decl    %edx
        subl    $16, %ecx
        testl   %edx, %edx
        jle     .L3
        cmpl    %ecx, %eax
        jl      .L6
.L3:
        movl    %ebx, %eax
        popl    %ebx
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: The `movl` instructions will not change the flags, so there is an instruction you haven't shown that will set the flags that the first `jle .L3` will examine.

Comment: "that means to jump to .L3 if something is lesser," -- `jle` actually means "Jump if Lesser-than-or-Equal", and you should also remember that it is generally for signed comparison. (The unsigned equivalent is `jbe`.)

Comment: Are you talking about the `jle` right after `test` or EDX against itself?  That's the same as comparing against zero.  If you mean the first one, you posted truncated output.  That's definitely not the top of a compiler-generated function, so just look at the whole thing and you'll see a flag-setting instruction.  Possibly `cmp`, possibly something else.

Comment: To add to 1201ProgramAlarm comment: Doing a `cmp` or `test` (among others) sets the flags.  Those flags *stay* set until you do another instruction that sets them again.  The movl instructions don't set the flags, so the flags will stay set to whatever instruction came before them that does set the flags.  Why put the set and jle so far apart?  While it can make reading the code a bit more challenging for humans, interleaving instructions can allow the processor to execute several different types of instructions at once (yes, it really does that).